# File close not working

Tags: perl, csv

i'm having a little problem with my perl script. I'm trying to convert the contents of an HTML file to CSV. That part isn't a problem. I'm doing exact the same thing for 2 HTML file's and expect 2 CSV files as a result. Everything is working fine except for 1 thing. The First CSV file is perfectly fine, but the Second CSV file contains all the text from the first PLUS the text for the second.... I pasted my script and removed the lines for the data extraction and HTML download. So the remaining part below is the plain file-handling... What am i missing here????

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

..
my $saveFileName = "x";
my $saveCsvName = "x";

sub parse_page{      
  open(CSV, ">".$saveCsvName);
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
  $tree->parse_file($saveFileName);
  my @adds = $tree->look_down(sub { lc($_[0]->attr('class')) eq 'ad_row' });
  foreach $add(@adds){ print CSV $stuff."\n";  } #do stuff and print  
  $tree->delete;
  close(CSV);
}

# Main -----------------------------------------------------
$saveFileName = "A_".$vandaag.".html";
$saveCsvName = "A_".$vandaag.".csv";
parse_page();

$saveFileName = "B_".$vandaag.".html";
$saveCsvName = "B_".$vandaag.".csv";
parse_page();
```

Comment: Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in that program? I think you don't. Add those two at the top, then fix all the errors they will give you (like an undeclared `$add` in the `foreach` loop) and then [edit] your question with the updated program please.

Comment: If you can't be sure there will never be field or line delimiters in your field data, use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV_XS) to write your CSV data.

Comment: I removed the double-quote as it is not relevant to my question. Also the contents of the CSV file are perfectly fine. The only problem is the 2nd file having also the contents of the first file...

Comment: Fair enough. But please make it run with strict and warnings. Otherwise it's going to be guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, after adding `use strict` and `use warnings` i had to declare some variables i forgot (the `$add` in the `foreach` was only one of them ). One of them was pretty nasty. But after resolving that my little problem is gone....

The nasty one (Use of uninitialized value in lc at #): turned out:

```
my @adds = $tree->look_down(sub { lc($_[0]->attr('class')) eq 'ad_row' });
```

should be:

```
my @adds = $tree->look_down(sub { (defined $_[0]->attr('class')) and lc($_[0]->attr('class')) eq 'ad_row' });
```

Thnks for the support!

Comment: A valuable lesson in why 'use strict; use warnings' is good practice I think! :)

Comment: hum.... That change won't do anything but silence a spurious warning. It was one of your other changes that made the difference.

Comment: You are right. The use strict/warnings helped me removing all warnings. That solved the problem. And i showed this one because it was a hard one (for me) to fix.